# SQL. Hive. Select median

Tags: sql, select, hive

completely new to Hive,  I have a database like this:

```
Cust |   Visited   |  Purchased
--------------------------------
id01 | Novem | Computer
id02 | March | Printer 
id03 | Decem | [empty]
id01 | April | Phone
id02 | Augus | Laptop 
id01 | Januar| Monitor
id01 | Febr  |  [empty]
id03 | Septem| Keyboard
```

Can you help me to find out the median number of purchased items per customer?

As for average, I suppose I can do the following:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct(Cust)) from table where Purchased !="";
```

But not sure how to calculate median.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- count each customer number of purchased items
- median is a private case percentile = `percentile(cnt,0.5)`

---

```
select      percentile(cnt,0.5) 

from       (select      count(*)  as cnt
            from        mytable 
            where       Purchased !=""
            group by    Cust
            ) t
;
```

> 2.0

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.